# Pause the audio from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, playback

I want to put the background music on the website and pause/play the music by a custom botton. 
First I used the `<audio>`, but chrome doesn't allow it to autoplay. So now I combine `<audio>` and `<iframe>` to make the music autoplay. But I don't know how to pause/play the music by `<iframe>`. 
Here's my code.

```
<script>
    var musicIframe = document.getElementById("iframeAudio");
    var musicAudio = document.getElementById("audioAudio");
    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);

    if (!isChrome) {
        $('#iframeAudio').remove();
        $("#music__btn--id").click(function() {
            if (musicAudio.paused) {
                musicAudio.play();
                $("#music__btn--id").removeClass("music__pause").addClass("play"); // change to the play button
            } else {
                musicAudio.pause();
                $("#music__btn--id").removeClass("play").addClass("music__pause"); // change to the pause button
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#audioAudio').remove();
        $("#music__btn--id").click(function() {
            if (musicIframe.paused) {
                $("#iframeAudio").attr("src", "./images/music.mp3");
                $("#music__btn--id").removeClass("music__pause").addClass("play"); // change to the play button

            } else {
                $("#iframeAudio").removeAttr("src");
                $("#music__btn--id").removeClass("play").addClass("music__pause"); // change to the pause button

            }
        });
    }
    </script>

<div class="music">
        <a class="music__btn" id="music__btn--id"></a>
        <iframe id="iframeAudio" src="./images/music.mp3" allow="autoplay" style="display:none"></iframe> 
        <audio id="audioAudio" src="./images/music.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></audio>
    </div>
```

And when I use IE to open the page, it shows up a small player window, How can I disable it?

Comment: Your autoplay hack probably isn't going to continue to work.  Why have it anyway?

Comment: Or how can I do to make music autoplay in every broswers?

Comment: You can't.  Thanks to years of abuse of this functionality, this feature is gone and isn't coming back.

Comment: So what if I keep using this autoplay hack, how can I solve these following problems?